# Browser automatic zoom in on high-dpi screens

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, browser, internet-explorer, opera

At work I use two displays, I have a full hd (1920 x 1080), 24 inch monitor, and I have the display of my laptop, which is also full hd, but its physical size is only 15 inches, so its DPI is higher.

If I open a website in Internet Explorer and I drag the window between my two screens, IE seems to automatically change the zoom setting to a higher value on my laptop screen.

Stack Overflow on the 24 inch screen:
[image]

Stack Overflow on the 15 inch screen:
[image]

The important thing to note is that the DPI setting in Windows is NOT set to a higher value in the Screen Resolution settings (I don't like to use that because many apps handle it so poorly), so it is only a mechanism of IE itself.

I tried the same with different browsers, but by default they do not provide this mechanism, and I couldn't find any setting to turn this on.
Is it possible to have the same behaviour with either Chrome, Firefox or Opera? (Currently I use Chrome, but this single feature is so important for me that I would be willing to switch to FF or Opera for this. I tried IE for a day but I couldn't get used to it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're open to changing the default zoom level for chrome on both monitors, you can give this extension a try. It's not exactly what you're looking for, but it may be the best option currently.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/optizoom/pboiiapkapflomkknmedcjmhdfepfdje

Answer (score 1):

While that would be a great feature I think IE is the only one that works (and I think it is because of changes they made in Windows 8 on how multi-monitor displays work).

I am guessing a Chrome extension could be written that detects the DPI and zooms the page - couldn't find any in the store through a quick search. Maybe you should write one.

Cheers.